# How to convert specular roughness to diffuse roughness

Tags: shaders

So I know that the diffuse roughness value of the diffuse bsdf activates the oren-nayer model for higher roughness values and I also know that the specular roughness values do not represent the diffuse roughness values. Is there a way to convert specular roughness values to diffuse roughness values or are those two values completely independant of each other.
This thread [What does the Roughness setting on a diffuse shader do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/what-does-the-roughness-setting-on-a-diffuse-shader-do) suggests a formula like this: diffuse_roughness=specular_roughness/3 but it also mentions that this formula was just simply eye balled rather than derived through physical models.

Comment: I don't think specular is related to roughness, it relates to ior,https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in the sense that specular reflection is somthing completely unrelated to roughness and no in the sense that this wasn't what I asked. If it clarifies a little some refer to specular roughness also to glossy roughness, so the roughness value on the gloosy or anisotropic bsdfs.